# How to create VPN connection In Jessie 8.5

Tags: vpn

I am trying to create a `VPN` connection in `Debian Jessie 8.5`. To do this, I first installed `OPENVPN` by typing these commands in bash:
`sudo apt-get install openvpn`
`sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome`
But, as we see in the picture below, the save button is not active, even after entering all the data I was supposed to provide in order to create the connection:
[image]

My problem now is that the save button is not active to let me create and use the connection. Would you please tell me how to make it responsible and working?

Comment: Are you running this as `root`?

Comment: No as far as I know. Actually I have ran it via `System -> Preferences -> Network Connections` and I am a regular user. Also, I have not ran this from terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

openvpn requires an ssl cert, even if you don't want to have certs for user auth, or for tls firewall.

Import the ssl cert from openvpn, then you can save the profile.

openvpn certs;

```
ca.crt (must have)
user.crt (optional: user auth)
user.key (optional: user auth)
ta.crt (optional: firewall)
```

sample config using all 3x cert:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 192.168.0.2
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert user.crt
key user.key
auth-user-pass tmp.ovpn
comp-lzo yes
nobind
auth-nocache
script-security 2
reneg-sec 21600
tls-auth ta.key 1
cipher AES-256-CFB8
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
```

Comment: The connection is now set. Thank you very much for helping me with this all valuable guideline. Awesome.